# Run on Unity Main Thread from Background Threads using a TaskScheduler reference connected to the UnitySynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, background-process

I am working on a system to run tasks on background threads (non unity main thread) but need the ability to run code on the main thread intermittently. I found that I can use the `Task.Factory` to launch a `Task` on a specific `TaskScheduler` and that I can get a reference to such a scheduler from the `UnitySynchronizationContext` which runs all tasks on the Unity main thread. This seems to work fine in this example below where a main thread task is launched from a background task:

```cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class AsyncExploration : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TaskScheduler unityScheduler;

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Main Thread is id {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}/{System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
        // capturing reference
        unityScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Task running in Default Task Scheduler
        Task.Run(() => {
            Debug.Log($"Random task running on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            // Starting Task using the Unity Scheduler
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                Debug.Log($"Inner task with unity scheduler running on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, unityScheduler);
        });
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
> Main Thread is id 1/1
> Random task running on thread 966
> Inner task with unity scheduler running on thread 1
```

Can such a reference stored in a global variable be used to reliably run tasks on the main thread or are there any problems or downsides I am potentially overlooking?

Comment: I would recommend to look into [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) it ca be installed as a package and provides a lot of enhancements for async coding in Unity - among those seamless switching between Unity main thread and async awaited tasks

Comment: Thank you, yes UniTask is great! I would do this but my current project has certain restrictions with including external plugins.

Comment: I think it is fine this way .. UniTask internally basically does sometimes pretty similar and uses TaskScheduler as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's perfectly fine caching the TaskScheduler returned from `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` or the `SynchronizationContext` itself.**

**Why?**

Consider this code

```
// UI Thread
// Here SynchronizationContext.Current is captured
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // Here we are on the ThreadPool
    await Task.Delay(1000);
});
// Here SynchronizationContext.Current is restored
// Ui Thread
Something();
```

When you await a Task your current `SynchronizationContext` is captured (i.e. is saved into a variable), and it will be used to run the continuation.

**Note That Task can run indefinitely long! So that Synchronization Context should be valid indefinitely long!**

**Can you cache `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`?**

If you take a look at the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,30e7d3d352bbb730), you'll se that `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` returns an instance of `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`.

- In the constructor it immediately saves in a private field the current `SynchronizationContext`.
- While in the `QueueTask()` method *(That is the method is called when you schedule a Task using `Task.Factory.StartNew(actionDoSchedule,..,..,taskScheduler)`)*, just uses that SynchronizationContext to execute the Task.

**So the TaskScheduler is valid until the SynchronizationContext is valid. But the SynchronizationContext is always valid!**